# ReactJS: Как присвоить переменным результат fetch(список объектов)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Новичок в js: Необходимо использовать переменные storeProducts(массив объектов) и detailProduct(конкретный объект) далее в программе, но они не видны за пределами getDetails. Как решить данную дилемму? Пробовал присваивать без асинхронной функции и await, но в таком случае, вместо массива объектов возвращают Promise {}.

```
let tempProducts = [];


async function getDetails(products, product){
  const storeProducts = await fetch('https:/products/').then(res => res.json());
  const detailProduct = await fetch('https:/products/:id').then(res => res.json());
}

getDetails();

Object.keys(storeProducts/*undefined*/).forEach(item => tempProducts.push({ ...item })
  );

const initialState = {
  products: tempProducts,
  productDetails: { ...detailProduct/*undefined*/ }
};
```

Спасибо за ответ, пардон за банальность вопроса

Answer (score 0):

```
let getData = async () => {
  const response = await fetch("api");
  let result = await response.json();
  console.log(result);
};
```

A вообще, я в своих проектах предпочитаю axios обычному fetch'у. Намного удобнее как по мне.

Comment: Дело срочное. В идеале, надо и стейт делать, но решение нужно максимально компактное и быстрое.

Comment: А чем мое решение не подходит?

Comment: Полагаю, что подходит, но  выдало: Failed to compile
./src/global-state/product.js
  Line 23:  Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected "=>"

  21 | // getDetails();
  22 | 
> 23 | async getData =() => {
     |               ^
  24 |   const response = await fetch("api");
  25 |   const responseItem = await fetch("api");
  26 |   let storeProducts = await response.json();

Comment: Да, есть такое, ошибочка. Исправил код в основном комментарии

Comment: Ух..storeProducts detailProduct все так же недоступны за пределами async функции getData. 
Failed to compile
./src/global-state/product.js
  Line 30:  'storeProducts' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 35:  'detailProduct' is not defined  no-undef

Comment: Ну это уже другой вопрос. В таком случае можно попробовать в стейт сетить нужные данные, полученные после запроса к апи

Comment: Да, пробую. Думал, можно без seState обойтись